# configure: error: invalid MySQL root directory

Tags: mysql, centos, percona

I've a problem installing sphinx with percona 5.6 on centos 6.4.

I'm getting the following error while building from source:

```
******************************************************************************
ERROR: cannot find MySQL include files.

Check that you do have MySQL include files installed.
The package name is typically 'mysql-devel'.

If include files are installed on your system, but you are still getting
this message, you should do one of the following:

1) either specify includes location explicitly, using --with-mysql-includes;
2) or specify MySQL installation root location explicitly, using --with-mysql;
3) or make sure that the path to 'mysql_config' program is listed in
   your PATH environment variable.

To disable MySQL support, use --without-mysql option.
******************************************************************************
```

Percona-Server-devel is installed:

```
rpm -qa | grep -i percona
percona-release-0.0-1.x86_64
Percona-Server-server-56-5.6.16-rel64.2.el6.x86_64
Percona-Server-client-56-5.6.16-rel64.2.el6.x86_64
Percona-Server-devel-56-5.6.16-rel64.2.el6.x86_64
Percona-Server-shared-56-5.6.16-rel64.2.el6.x86_64
```

What I've tried:

```
locate "libmysql"

    /usr/lib64/libmysqlclient.so.18
    /usr/lib64/libmysqlclient.so.18.0.0
    /usr/lib64/libmysqlclient_r.so.18
    /usr/lib64/libmysqlclient_r.so.18.0.0
    /usr/lib64/mysql/libmysqlclient.so.16
    /usr/lib64/mysql/libmysqlclient.so.16.0.0
    /usr/lib64/mysql/libmysqlclient_r.so.16
    /usr/lib64/mysql/libmysqlclient_r.so.16.0.0
    /usr/lib64/mysql/libmysqlservices.a
```

than:

```
  ./configure --with-mysql=/usr/lib64/mysql --with-mysql-libs=/usr/lib64/mysql
  ./configure --with-mysql=/usr/lib64 --with-mysql-libs=/usr/lib64
  ./configure --with-mysql=/usr/bin/mysql --with-mysql-libs=/usr/bin/mysql
  ./configure --with-mysql=/usr
```

> configure: error: invalid MySQL root directory '/usr/lib64/mysql';
>   neither bin/mysql_config, nor include/ and lib/ were found there

which mysql_config

```
/usr/bin/mysql_config
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried installing mysql-devel ?

```
sudo yum install mysql-devel
```

If properly setup, try as suggested in the error message to point to these libs manually using a command like the following one (to be adapted to your environment)

```
./configure --with-mysql-includes=/usr/local/src/mysql-XXX/include
```

Comment: You can't have mysql-devel and percona-devel at the same time!

Comment: You are probably right, but the error message start by "ERROR: cannot find MySQL include files."
So you have to point to this one way or an other. Have you tried --with-mysql-includes (make it points to personal lib and check it out)